# Posso gerar um certificado para uma app IOS sem ter um dispositivo Apple?

Tags: ios, app, certificado-digital

Estou desenvolvendo um app via phonegap e gostaria de gerar para IOS também, só que eu preciso de um certificado, e pelo que vi esse certificado tem que ser gerado por um Mac.

Existe alguma outra forma de gerar esse arquivo do certificado (CSR), para que eu possa criar o meu app?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o método mencionando anteriormente, ou pode ter acesso a um Mac usando um serviço como [Mac In Cloud](http://www.macincloud.com), para testar a sua app nos simuladores e fazer o build da sua app no XCode. De qualquer forma, você precisa da licença de desenvolvedor Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Sim, existe uma forma, usando o [Phonegap Builder](http://build.phonegap.com) eles tem uma documentação que mostra como fazer, [veja aqui](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/signing_signing-ios.md.html#iOS%20Signing). Nâo vou postar aqui porque é bastante extensa.

Porém você ainda vai precisar do certificado da Apple.